# Como ir buscar info de folha de excel para fazer drop down em Visual Basic

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho fazer um dropdown com informação que já tenho numa folha de excel em Visual Basic, como faço para ir buscar essa mesma informação? E já fazer com que não haja informação repetida?

Exemplo:

```
colunaA

a

a

a

b

b

b

b

c

c

d

e

e
```

E o dropdown do Visual Basic só mostrar `a b c d e`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

#### Código

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim UltimaLinha As Long, i As Long
    Dim ValorTrim As String
    Dim unicos As Collection
    Dim intervalo As range
    
    Set unicos = New Collection
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1")
    
    With ws
        'Última linha da coluna "A"
        UltimaLinha = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set intervalo = .range("$A$1:$A$" & UltimaLinha)
        On Error Resume Next
        'Cria uma Collection de valores Únicos e não vazios
        For Each celula In intervalo
            ValorTrim = Trim(celula)
            If ValorTrim = "" Then GoTo ProximoValor
            unicos.Add ValorTrim, ValorTrim
ProximoValor:
        Next celula
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Gera uma Lista com os valores únicos e não vazios
        For i = 1 To unicos.Count
            Lista = Lista & unicos.Item(i) & ","
        Next i
        With .range("B1:B1").Validation
            'Apaga a Validação existente
            .Delete
            'Cria uma validação com os dados da lista
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Lista
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado

Comment: Favor ler [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104)